# Porque length devuelve el valor de la mascara y no el resultado real?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-10g

Estaba tratando de hacer un pad a izquierda de espacios a un número, para que en mi vista se vieran todos formateados (en la vista no se pueden formatear).

Cuando pruebo la función que sigue:

```
LENGTH (TO_CHAR(a.variacion*100,'999990.99'))
```

oh casualidad todos los números miden 11.

Sin embargo, como se observa en la siguiente lista, esto no es real. Entonces, de donde saca Oracle ese 11???

```
11      -59.00
11        1.00
11      -76.00
11       -5.00
11      -24.00
11       37.00
11      -47.00
11      -14.00
11      -21.00
11      -50.00
11        0.00
11     6032.00
11      -64.00
11       -6.00
11      -28.00
11      -59.00
```

Como aclaración, si cambio la mascara a otra cosa, por ejemplo a `TO_CHAR(a.variacion*100,'990.99')`, sale lo siguiente:

```
8    -59.00
8      1.00
8    -76.00
8     -5.00
8    -24.00
8     37.00
8    -47.00
8    -14.00
8    -21.00
8    -50.00
8      0.00
8   #######
8    -64.00
8     -6.00
8    -28.00
8    -59.00
```

O sea que el problema es la mascara.. pero que tiene que ver???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es el comportamiento esperado para los [Modelos de Formato](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00211) utilizados en la función `TO_CHAR`.

Los `9` los sustituirá por espacios (`' '`) si no toman ningún valor y además agregará un espacio por delante, como podrás comprobar en esta consulta:

```
SELECT LENGTH (TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'999990.99')) Longitud,
       TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'999990.99') Texto,
       '<'||TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'999990.99')||'>' ConEspacios
FROM dual;
```

Resultado:

```
Longitud | Texto     | ConEspacios
---------|-----------|---------------
      10 |    -59.00 | <    -59.00>
```

Si te fijas, tu trama corresponde con el resultado exceptuando que `TO_CHAR` ha agregado un espacio de más (marcado en el ejemplo con el caracter `_`):

```
 '999990.99'
<_   -59.00>
```

Para eliminarlo debes utilizar el denominado **Fill Mode Modifier** (`FM`) como te indica la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216):

> The FM and FX modifiers, used in format models in the TO_CHAR function, control blank padding and exact format checking.

```
LENGTH (TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'FM999990.99'))
```

Sin embargo y como te he explicado antes, si quieres **conservar la parte decimal** te aconsejo que cambies la trama decimal de 99 a 00:

```
LENGTH (TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'FM999990.00'))
```

Te pongo el ejemplo completo:

```
SELECT LENGTH (TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'FM999990.00')) Longitud,
       TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'FM999990.00') Texto,
       '<'||TO_CHAR(-0.59*100,'FM999990.00')||'>' ConEspacios
FROM dual;
```

Un saludo